# Using Wordpress, BuddyPress and Mailgun but HTML mails not working, only plain, any solution exist for this?

Tags: wordpress, html-email, mailgun

I'm using the above-mentioned combination and when a BuddyPress sending out an e-mail with mailgun it comes as plain, not HTML. When I turn off mailgun plugin, I'm using my phpmail which I don't want but I get nice HTML messages.

I tried WP-Mail SMTP also but not working as well. Actually with that only the WP mails going out with mailgun, Buddypress mails using my phpmail so this plugin not good again. Mailgun plugin is good, everything going out using the mailgun system, but when buddypress sending out something comes as a plain email instead of HTML. I had a look on other forums, google, this site, but couldn't find any solution for this.

Comment: check for the mime types being sent, you might be sending out only text version?

Comment: @Syfer I found this, in the mailgun plugin because I think if we have to modify anything it should be there.
function get_mime_content_type($filepath, $default_type = 'text/plain')
{
    if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        return mime_content_type($filepath);
    } elseif (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
        $fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $ret = finfo_file($fi, $filepath);
        finfo_close($fi);

        return $ret;
    } else {
        return $default_type;
    }
}
So what if I change this: $default_type = 'text/plain') to 'text/html'?